# How can I change a bitmap image to "X" count of colors indexed in image

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm developing an application that crops an image to a width and height people can change, but I want it can save the image with the number of colors people want, for example: I pick an image .png, crop to 102x96 and then save with the number of indexed colors I want.

I have tried a lot of things, but I can't save with the number of colors I want.. I only can save in an indexed default format like 1bpp, 4bpp or 8bpp.

```
//this function will save the image
public void SaveFile()
{

    string extensions = "png";

    string path = FileBrowser.SaveFile("Save File", "", "MyFile", extensions);

    Debug.Log("Save file: " + path);
pathz = path;

System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort callback =
 new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
System.Drawing.Bitmap image = new Bitmap(pathh);
//Bitmap clone = image.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
//here I crop the file
System.Drawing.Image pThumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(int.Parse(x.text), int.Parse(y.text), callback, new System.IntPtr());


Bitmap xx = pThumbnail.Clone() as Bitmap;
    //here I save
xx.Save(pathz);

  // this place is the way I tried to put it in indexed color
 // Bitmap Result = xx.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, xx.Width, xx.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
// Bitmap Result2 = Result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, xx.Width, xx.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

}
```

The final file was saved with the crop, but I can't make this final image with e.g. 32 colors, or 64 colors, or 16 colors.

Comment: The file format probably does not support these numbers of indexed colours so that's why you can't do that.

Comment: I only what to convert the image to an another image with the number of colors I want and the PixelFormat have to be indexed

Comment: Can you please re-write this with proper grammar and terminology?

Comment: Sorry, I'm brazilian and I'm learning how to speak in english too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe Windows has any [color quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization) algorithms included - you would have to implement one yourself, such as [Wu's algorithm](http://www.ece.mcmaster.ca/~xwu/cq.c).

Comment: Is too hard.. :(

Comment: There are [examples](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66341/A-Simple-Yet-Quite-Powerful-Palette-Quantizer-in-C) available.

Comment: Thanks So Much @NetMage
DistinctSelectionQuantizer Work for me!
I using Unity3D, and work very well!